# Entropy of X+Y where Y is normal and independent from X?

Tags: normal-distribution, entropy, information-theory

Let's say $X$ and $Y$ are two random variables where $Y \sim N(0, \sigma) $ and independent from $X$. Is there a general way to express the entropy $H(X+Y)$ in terms $H(X)$? 
$X$ can be any random variable.

Comment: What does "$P$" mean?  What do you know or assume about $X$?

Comment: Sorry that my question was unclear, edited

Comment: Thank you.  Are you sure this is what you want ask?  Or are you trying to ask about the entropy of the random variable $X+Y$ itself?  Please note that $P(X+Y)$ is  a random variable, but its entropy will likely differ quite a bit from that of $X+Y.$

Comment: OK.  Are you familiar with how entropy behaves with sums of independent variables?  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)#Further_properties.

Comment: As far as I understand, I can express $H(X,Y)=H(X)+H(Y)$ if $X$ and $Y$ are independent

Comment: And isn't that exactly what you have stipulated in your question?

Comment: I meant I only know how to get the entropy of joint random variables $H(X,Y)$, not the entropy of the sum $H(X+Y)$

Comment: Your assumption of independence is equivalent to stating the joint distribution is determined by the distributions of each variable separately.  The Wikipedia link and your previous comment both fully answer the question: entropy is an additive function of independent random variables.

Comment: Can you clarify that a bit more? I don't really see any direct connection between $H(X,Y)$ and $H(X+Y)$ despite the independence assumption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like sending a signal, $X$, through and [additive white Gaussian noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_white_Gaussian_noise) channel with variance, $\sigma^2$, where $Z=X+Y$ is the received signal with noise. One thing we can say is that if the $E(X^2) = P$, then $I(X;Z) \leq 1/2 \log (1+P/\sigma^2)$. That is relevant because $I(X;Z) = H(Z)-H(Z|X) = H(X+Y)-H(Z|X) = H(X+Y) - 1/2 \log (2 \pi e \sigma^2)$, and therefore $H(X+Y) \leq 1/2 \log (1+P/\sigma^2) + 1/2 \log (2 \pi e \sigma^2) = 1/2 \log (2 \pi e (\sigma^2+P))$.

That is not very satisfying as it only gives an upper bound and it is in terms of the second moment, not the entropy of $X$. One thing we can see from this bound is that it is saturated if $X$ is normal. If, on the other hand, $X$ is a delta function (e.g. X = 0, always), then $H(X+Y) = 1/2 \log (2 \pi e \sigma^2)$ even though $H(X)=-\infty$. I don't think there will be a general relationship, as I found many papers deriving relationships when $X,Y$ were in specific parametric families.

Answer (score 2):

This has been bothering me since I wrote my last answer. There's a much better answer based on the entropy power inequality, but I'll leave the old answer in case it's useful to anybody. 
The entropy power, $e^{2/n H(X)}$, where $n$ is the dimension of the random variable and H is differential entropy, is also the volume of the typical set for the distribution p(x).  It seems intuitive that adding two independent random variables should increase the size of the typical set. This is reflected in the [entropy power inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_power_inequality), which can be rearranged as follows. 
$$H(X+Y) \geq n/2 \log (e^{2/n H(X)}+e^{2/n H(Y)})$$

In your case H(Y) is known and Gaussian. As the noise variance goes to zero the lower bound goes to H(X), as expected.